# Can't get Python ldap3 to show schema

Tags: python, ldap, ldap3

I've got a project to delete the duplicates in a large LDAP database, but so far ...

I am just trying to get the schema and I can't see anything:

```
>> import ldap3
>>> s = ldap3.Server('ldaps://omitted')
>>> s.schema
>>> s2 = ldap3.Server('ldaps://omitted',get_info=ldap3.ALL)
>>> s2.schema
>>> s2.info
>>> s.info
```

(omitted is the URL as I don't have permission yet from my employer.)

Any idea about this? The server is set up behind security and doesn't require any authentication to connect.

Comment: Why do you need the schema in the executing program?

Comment: I need to know how to query for the data; how to do that without seeing the schema?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work using ldapsearch instead of Python.

I was helped by a local guru; it needed the **.ldaprc** file in the home directory. The key parameter in this file was **TLS_REQCERT ALLOW**.

Complete command line was like this (corporate identity blanked out):

`ldapsearch -x -D "SEA\mmcwiggins" -b "DC=SEA,DC=CORP,DC=*****,DC=COM" -E pr=1000/noprompt -H ldaps://lbdc.sea.corp.******.com -W  sAMAccountName='*'  >bigresult`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to bind your connection first. Try this:

```py
from ldap3 import Connection, Server

# take 636 for secured connection, use_ssl=True may be necessary
server = Server('myhost.company.com', port=389) 
cnx = Connection(server, user='cn=user', password='whatever')
# either use auto_bind=True or set bind explicitly
cnx.bind()
# now you should be able to see the schema
# Caution: depending on the schema, it may take quite long to show it
print(server.schema)
```

Comment: I was binding it ... I tried exactly what you have above except it's **server.schema** not **cnx.schema** and I just get **None** as output...

Comment: Is it going back to prompt immediately or are you maybe just impatient? I tried it against an AD server, and it took quite a while until I got an output on my screen.

Comment: It came back with None immediately.

Comment: But you can query your directory without any problem, right?

Comment: What do you mean, 'query your directory'? If I can't even see the schema, how do I do anything else?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have a server here, which responds to `server.schema` properly, but does not give output to  `server.info`. What I also recognized is that it may be related to the user you're using and the corresponsing access rights. Sorry, but I may not have a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but I have made some progress. The big info was that the server **does** require authentication even though the PHP code I first saw didn't seem to be using it.

I now have this code:

```
from pprint import pprint
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SAFE_SYNC, ALL

search_base = '*omitted*'
search_filter = '(uid=mmcwiggins)'
attrs = ['*']

server = Server('ldaps://*omitted*', get_info=ALL)
mypass = 'not.really.the.pass'.encode('iso-8859-1')
connect = Connection(server, user='mmcwiggins', password=mypass)
connect.bind()
print(connect)
print(server.schema)
```

That produces this response:

```
ldaps://lbdc.secret.company.com:636 - ssl - user: mmcwiggins - not lazy - unbound - open - <local: 10.184.200.19:49737 - remote: 10.184.67.152:636> - tls not started - listening - SyncStrategy - internal decoder
None
```

Any ideas after seeing this?